# Python: Prevent fileinput from adding newline characters

Tags: python, file-io

I am using a Python script to **find and replace** certain strings in text files of a given directory. I am using the `fileinput` module to ease the find-and-replace operation, i.e., the file is read, text replaced and written back to the same file.

The code looks as follows:

```
import fileinput
def fixFile(fileName):
    # Open file for in-place replace
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(fileName, inplace=1):
        line = line.replace("findStr", "replaceStr")
        print line  # Put back line into file
```

The problem is that the written files have:

1. One blank line inserted after *every* line.
2. Ctrl-M character at the end of *every* line.

How do I prevent these extra appendages from getting inserted into the files?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your newlines are coming from the print function

use:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write ('some stuff')
```

and your line breaks will go away

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed both extra lines & Ctrl-M characters. I have chosen your reply as the solution to this problem. Go ahead & add some extra information to your answer if you wish.

Comment: Can you please add a little detail? :)

Comment: This might have changed, if I swap `print` to `sys.stdout.write` it prints to the console and the file ends up empty.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
print line,
```

or

```
file.write(line)
```

to fix extra newlines.

As of [Ctrl]-[M] - that is probably caused by input files in DOS encoding.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution removes the blank lines but still has the Ctrl-M characters. Another person has already suggested an answer which solves both for me.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of this:

```
print line  # Put back line into file
```

use this:

```
print line,  # Put back line into file
```

Comment: @Paul Fleming, putting a , after the print line worked for me.  Can you explain why the comma keeps a new line from being written?  Thank you.

Comment: @teamg not my answer, and don't know the answer to your Q. Sorry!

Comment: @kwamke, putting a comma after the print line worked for me.  Can you explain why the comma keeps a new line from being written?  Thank you.

Comment: I found the explanation here.  https://www.afternerd.com/blog/how-to-print-without-a-newline-in-python/

Answer (score 6):

Change the first line in your for loop to:

`line = line.rstrip().replace("findStr", "replaceStr")`

Comment: Please explain the down-vote. This method addresses the newline problem (although I was not able to reproduce the Ctrl-M problem, so cannot speak to it).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it is essentially a "hack", removing the original newline rather than just avoiding adding an additional one in the first place (covered by other answers a year before you posted yours!). That's probably why you got downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Due to every iteration print statement ends with newline, you are getting blank line between lines.

To overcome this problem, you can use strip along with print.

```
import fileinput
def fixFile(fileName):
  for line in fileinput.FileInput(fileName, inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("findStr", "replaceStr")
    print line.strip()
```

Now, you can see blank lines are striped.

Comment: This will also remove indentation, however, which may not be desired. Instead use rstrip() :)

Answer (score 0):

For the update on Python 3.4, you can just use:

```
print(line, end = '')
```

to avoid the insertion of a new line.

Comment: Python **4.3**?? :)

Comment: As much as I enjoyed seeing 4.3 in the original answer, I edited to 3.4 to avoid confusion.