# subprocess.call with sed pass variable

Tags: python, sed, subprocess

I am trying to run Python script with `subprocess.call` to add a line after matching pattern. Here's the ways :

`addline1` is variable and has the value say `"hello world1"`

`filename1` is the variable containing path and file name for example `"/tmp/path1/filename.conf"`

in the `filename.conf`, it has ~35 lines and i wanted to insert one line after matching string `"ReWriteEngine On"`

```
subprocess.call(["sed","-i" ,'/ReWriteEngine On/a', addline1,filename])
```

and it fails with below exception:

```
**sed: -e expression #1, char 16: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'**
```

Can any one please advice any correction to be made ?

Code tried with `fileinput` instead of `sed`

```
import fileinput
processing_foo1s = False
for line in fileinput.input('/tmp/filename1/mod_wl_ohs.conf', inplace=1):
    if line.startswith("RewriteEngine On"):
        processing_foo1s = True
    else:
        if processing_foo1s:
            print 'foo bar'
            processing_foo1s = False
            print line
```

Comment: why not do it all with python itself?

Comment: with python itself ? can you elaborate ? you meant using os.system call ?

Comment: I even tried this way in python itself, this did not help to add new string :                                                                                
import fileinput

processing_foo1s = False

for line in fileinput.input('/tmp/filename1/mod_wl_ohs.conf', inplace=1):
  if line.startswith("RewriteEngine On"):
    processing_foo1s = True
  else:
    if processing_foo1s:
      print 'foo bar'
    processing_foo1s = False
  print line,

Comment: regarding `sed` issue, it can be solved by constructing string and passing to subprocess.. for ex: `sed_cmd = '/ReWriteEngine On/a' + addline1` and `subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', sed_cmd, filename1])`

Comment: sure - let me try and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the `sed` issue:

```
sed_cmd = '/ReWriteEngine On/a' + addline1
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', sed_cmd, filename1])
```

**Note:** Use `/^ReWriteEngine On/a` if the string has to match at start of line

With `fileinput`:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(filename1, inplace=1):
    print line,
    if line.startswith("ReWriteEngine On"):
        print 'foo bar'
```

Reference: [Python: Prevent fileinput from adding newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657186/python-prevent-fileinput-from-adding-newline-characters)