# How to remove or replace a "n" line of a csv file?

Tags: python

I have a csv file of more than 10 thousand lines. for each line I think replacing them with new content. It occurs to me to delete each line and add the new content or simply replace it.

With this small example, I hope to make myself understood
I know how to insert content in an "n" line, but not how to delete it. how can I do it?

```
mycsv.csv

name,last name  
yeison, smith
lola, boa
elmo, spitia
anderson, exneider
juan, ortega
```

this is my code,for example I want to add a line in the line 2 of my csv.:

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  lines.insert(2, 'german, ezequiel') #inserting a new line
  with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:
   f.write(''.join(lines))
```

for example, what do I have to do to eliminate / replace line number 3 of csv?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list. You can modify values in a list, so you don't need to insert and delete:

```
lines[2] = 'german, ezequiel'
```

Alternatively, there is a Python library for inplace editing of files. This means you don't have to read the entire file into memory in one go. See [**`fileinput.input`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input):

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input('mycsv.csv', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if f.lineno() == 2:
            print('german, ezequiel')
        else:
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Will this overwrite the same file? what is lineno()?

Comment: I linked the documentation.

Comment: ohh I tested your code, for what I am getting some spaces blank between lines?

Comment: Ah, it's because `line` has a newline at the end, and `print` also adds a newline. I'll fix the code. Apologies.

Comment: thanks for your help.. there are lines between with your new code.. and the line to replace is the 2? look please https://imgur.com/aEEEtVl

Comment: Hmm, is the csv created by Excel? Sometimes the line endings aren't as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657186/python-prevent-fileinput-from-adding-newline-characters

Comment: thanks, I solved with:         if f.lineno() == (3):
            print('german, ezequiel', end='\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line)

Comment: an ultimate question, how can the value of the column "name"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) and [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) modules to update the CSV file in-place:

```
import csv
import fileinput


replacements = {
    2: 'german, ezequiel',
    5: 'smith, john',
}

with fileinput.input(files=('mycsv.csv',), backup='.bak', inplace=True,
                     mode='r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    print(','.join(next(reader)))  # Copy header row.
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        if i in replacements:
            row = replacements.pop(i).replace(',', ' ').split()
        print(','.join(row))

print('done')
```

Afterwards, the `replacements` dictionary should be empty if all the replacements were made.